# Match all non-numeric characters between two underscores

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression to extract all non-numeric characters between two underscores from a string.

```
JohnDoe_King234_sample
```

I need the following output from the string: King

I have tried the following regular expression: `(?<=_).\D*(?=_)`
(Look positively forward for _ then match non numeric characters then look positively behind _ )

If my string is:

```
JohnDoe_King_sample
```

then my expression returns `King`. If my string is:

```
JohnDoe_King234_sample
```

then my expression does not match.

`(?<=_).\D*(?=_)`

Expected results: `King`

Actual results:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=_)[^_\d]+(?=\d*_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2T1Sh2/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=_)` - a `_` should be right before the current location
- `[^_\d]+` - any 1 or more chars other than `_` and digits -
- `(?=\d*_)` - there must be 0 or more digits followed with one `_` immediately to the right of the current location.

**NOTE**: In case you may have digits anywhere inside that substring between underscores, if you have a way to process the string with some programming language, you might consider a `_([^_]+)_` regex to extract the first match, then grab Group 1 value and remove all digits from it using a simple `\d+` pattern with a regex replace method/function.